# Interrupted loop

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

How would I create a batch file with an interrupted loop? At the momen I have a file with sort of a matrix-y feeling that does this...

```
:start

echo %random%%random%%random%%random%

goto start
```

but I would like too make it so the screen `clr`'s and then displays a bunch of exclamation points, kind of like an error type deal such as

```
:start

echo !!!!!!!!!!...etc

goto start
```

but how would I make an interrupted loop like that?

..mind you I'm a bit new-ish too batch, so I would be grateful for a little more special treatment in the explanation area of each line. Thanks :)..

Comment: What is it that will interrupt the loop though, how does it know when to stop echoing? I assume you want a loop that will keep going unless some condition is made, correct? Please explain so I can better visualize.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I'm assuming you want the program to display the error at random times. For this you can use a random number generator.

`set /a rndm=%random% * 10 / 32768 + 1`

This code will create a variable called "rndm" (this doesn't have to be called rndm, you can name this whatever you like), which is a random number between 1 and 10. If you want a bigger or smaller pool of possible numbers, you can change the 10 in the code to whatever you want. So if you want a random number between 1 and 3, you'd do this:

`set /a rndm=%random% * 3 /32768 + 1`

You can use this to generate a random chance of the error happening. If you want to have a 1 in 10 chance of exiting the loop, clearing the screen and entering a different loop you'd want your code to look  like this:

`@echo off
:start
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%
set /a rndm=%random% * 10 / 32768 + 1
if %rndm% == 1 goto errorstart
goto start`


`:errorstart
cls
:error
echo !!!!!!!!!!!!
goto error`

While the loop is executing, the program generates a random number between 1 and 10. Right after that it checks whether that number it's generated is 1. If it's not 1, it continues the loop. If it is, it jumps to the "errorstart" label. The command below the errorstart label clears the screen. The program then enters the error loop, where it echoes exclamation points until the program is closed.

This code should give you the effect you're looking for, but 1 in 10 is a bit too high of a chance for a program working this fast, so you might want to change that to 1 in 1000 or 1 in 10.000. That should make the initial loop last longer before the secondary loop kicks in.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? You should have brackets in the expression, eg `SET /a _rand=(%RANDOM%*10/32768)+1`. See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted but what purpose does the 32768+1 server and what's it for?

Comment: Yes, this program doesn't actually function correctly, mostly because id like it to loop back to the numbers and continuously flash every say one second or so.

Comment: @Xaxis Sorry for the late response, but if you want the program to go back to the first loop you could implement something similar to the code that exits the first loop into the second loop. It's mostly just copy-pasting and swapping some jump flags around.